# Some basic doubts about AWS DynamoDB 'Keys'

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, key, primary-key

I've seen these terms everywhere -

- Primary Key
- Sort Key
- Partition Key
- Secondary Key

---

But I seem to get confused with the names :

- Are the Partition Key and Primary Key the same thing? What are they?
- Does the same go with Sort Key and Secondary Index? What role would secondary key play if I add it?

Also, at the time of creating creating a DynamoDB table, I added `'Order ID'` as the Primary Key - now, I need to replace it with `'User ID'`, and make '`Order ID`' as the secondary key.

So, `Order ID` would be the 'Secondary Key', and `User ID` would be the 'Primary Key'
**How can this be achieved?**

Any help is appreciated! :) Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

> Are the Partition Key and Primary Key the same thing? What are they?

No.

A Primary Key is what uniquely identifies each item in the table.

A Partition Key is one possible kind of Primary Key, the other being Partition Key + Sort Key (i.e., a "composite" primary key, as you'd call it in other DB systems).

> Does the same go with Sort Key and Secondary Index? What role would secondary key play if I add it?

Sort key and Secondary Index are also different things.

A Sort Key can be used as a "second element" in a "composite key" in a Primary Key. In other words, a Primary Key can be of type "Partition Key" or "Partition Key + Sort Keu".

A Secondary Index is something else entirely. A secondary index allows you to perform different kinds of optimized queries on your table. It needs to know how you want to partition and sort your items: for a Local Secondary Index, you only specify a Sort Key since it will implicitly use the same Partition Key as the Primary Key. For a Global Secondary Index, you must specify a Partition Key and you can, optionally, specify a Sort Key (so in a sense a GSI is defined in a similar way to a Primary Key).

Take a look at this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.CoreComponents.html

It explains all that with a lot of examples.

> at the time of creating creating a DynamoDB table, I added 'Order ID' as the Primary Key - now, I need to replace it with 'User ID', and make 'Order ID' as the secondary key.

You can't do it.

It's not possible to change the Primary Key of a DynamoDB table.

Here's the relevant docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateTable.html

> I've seen these terms everywhere - [...]

As a final comment, just be aware that you may also see a few *other* terms, too. In the old days, DynamoDB used different terms for "Partition Key" and "Sort Key". They used to be called, respectively, "Hash Key" and "Range Key". You'll probably see a lot of reference to those names in SDKs, CLI parameters, etc.